# Hosting Angular application in Kestrel does not work with Docker

Tags: angular, docker, configuration-files, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a `angular 6` application that is hosted inside a `.NET Core` Server.The application works ,i can acess the pages/routes etc.
However when i put this `.NET`application inside docker and run it i get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8400/styles.3bb2a9d4949b7dc120a9.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8400/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

In my `docker` image i put the `Release` folder of the `.NET App` ,and in this folder i add :

```
-DockerImage
   -Release folder
     - Dockerfile
     - Config `json` file (i am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`)
     - `dist` folder (angular compiled application)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","Deploy.dll"]
```

The `.` root path in this case is the `Release` folder that has the items i mentioned in the upper section.

What is intriguing is that the `NET Core` depends on some files of the `dist` folder otherwise it would crash.And it doesn't ,it works just fine.

**Startup.cs**

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
                if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                } else
                    app.UseHsts();
                Config config = this.Configuration.GetSection("Config").Get<Config>();
                Config.Frontend frontend = this.Configuration.GetSection("Config:Frontend").Get<Config.Frontend>();

                string jsroot = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), frontend.PhysicalRoot);
                PhysicalFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(jsroot);

                DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions() {
                    DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { frontend.DefaultFileName },
                    FileProvider = provider,
                    RequestPath = frontend.RequestPath
                };
                app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
                    RequestPath = frontend.RequestPath,
                    FileProvider = provider
                });
            }
```

**Index.html** (from the `dist` folder )

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="treeview/styles.3bb2a9d4949b7dc120a9.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="treeview/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="treeview/polyfills.c6871e56cb80756a5498.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="treeview/main.a4ddb95d782e95e34c4a.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Config file**

```
{
  "Config": {
    "Frontend": {
      "PhysicalRoot": "./js",
      "RequestPath": "/treeview",
      "DefaultFileName": "index.html"
    },
    "Environment": {
      "ProdEnv": {
        "OwnAddress": {
          "Hostname": "0.0.0.0",
          "Port": 8400
        }
      },
      "DevEnv": {
        "OwnAddress": {
          "Hostname": "0.0.0.0",
          "Port": 8401
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**P.S** The `Config` type in the `.NET Core App` is just a `POCO` for the `Config` section of the config file.

The container is started with a `bash` script that starts a `docker-compose`

**Docker compoe**

```
version: '3.3'
services:

    front:
      image: ft
      container_name: front0
      build: ./front/publish
      networks:
        - redis-net
      ports:
        - 8400:8400
```

**Script.sh**

```
    dotnet build -c Release ../${hostServerSrc} >>out.txt  //building the release for the `.NET Server that hosts the angular app`
    dotnet publish -c Release ../${hostServerSrc} --output $(pwd)/${hostServerDest} >>out.txt  //publshing it to the folder that will be injected in the image
    cp  ./Configs/hostConfig.json ./front/publish  //copying the config file for the `.NET App`
    cp  -r ../${ngSrc}  ./front/publish/js //copying the angular compiled app

    docker-compose up --build  -d >>out.txt
```

**P.S 2**
It seems it can not find any file in the `js` folder.The `Request URL` is:
`http://localhost:8400/runtime.js`.

In the docker container i have all the files inside the `js` folder.
It might be because being in docker there is no more `localhost` ?

Comment: Share your `Dockerfile` and command line you use to start `docker`

Comment: How do you start the container? What is the command line? `docker run blahblah...`?

Comment: I have a `docker-compose` file started with a `shell` script.The server is running, it is accesible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine except one point for me.

You want your container to join `redis-net` network:

```
  networks:
    - redis-net
```

but I dont see this network defined in your `docker-compose` file.

Try one of the following:

Add network definition to `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    front:
      image: ft
      container_name: front0
      build: ./front/publish
      networks:
        - redis-net
      ports:
        - 8400:8400
networks:
  redis-net:
```

Or remove this line - `docker-compose` will create a default shiny bridged network for you, which works fine. If you dont plan to perform manual network manipulation, this is a great choice.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    front:
      image: ft
      container_name: front0
      build: ./front/publish
      ports:
        - 8400:8400
```

Comment: I have not showed all the `compose` folder and the `network` part because i wanted to be as concise as possible (still haven't managed to that though). On another note I have looked more carefully in the request.It appears it does not find the `js` files.It requests `GET` on `http://localhost:8400/runtime.js` and it does not find it.